# Socket remains ESTABLISHED even if remote process is stopped

Tags: socket

I am running a `celery` - `rabbitmq` configuration between a client and a server. The client process opens a connection on the server at port 5672. Using `netstat -np` on the server I confirm that since the socket reports ESTABLISHED.

The process on the client crashed and it doesn't exist anymore. But `netstat -np` still shows the connection ESTABLISHED. I also run `netstat -np` on the client and I confirm that no process has connection to the server on that port.

Why does the socket remains in ESTABLISHED status?

Comment: how long does it stay that way? my guess is less than 30-60 seconds, based on your server OS configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately it stays there more than that, at least 1 hour before I had to restart the service. By the way, I don't know if it is relevant, this is a `rabbitmq` server, and the client is connecting with `celery`. If needed, I should update the question.

Comment: Ah, then this is a completely different story. AMQP *requires* the server to stay open if the client does not close the connection properly (for long-running tasks). Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835138/rabbitmq-doesnt-close-connections-server-side

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So should those connections be closed or they will time-out after a period of time?

Comment: no problem ;) now, about the stale connections - you can close them manually using rabbitmqctl, write a script that does that for you from a cron job (both ugly) or if you can, switch on heartbeat and set the timeout to, say, 15-20% more than your longest known processing task. that should recycle those connections after heartbeat timeout, but it will also disconnect any client that has been busy for too long, so be careful.

Comment: If you can provide this information as an answer, in order for me to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMQP *requires* the server-side of the connection to stay open if the client does not close the connection properly (for long-running tasks). Read more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835138/rabbitmq-doesnt-close-connections-server-side).

You can close those connections manually using `rabbitmqctl` or write a script that does that for you from a cron job, but both are rather ugly outside approaches to an application-level problem.

If you can, switch on *heartbeat* and set the timeout to, say, 15-20% more than your longest known processing task. That should recycle those "dead" connections after a heartbeat timeout, but be careful as it will also disconnect any client that has been busy for too long.

More on [heartbeat](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html) and [rabbitmqctl](https://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html) (see section Miscellaneous).